# ConnectException Java

Tags: java, android, apache, servlets

I am writing a client server application, and everything was working fine until now. I didn't change anything but I upgrade the mac OS to maverick, I don't know if its related but I don't see what it could be. When I try to connect to the server, i have a java.net.ConnectException. The client and server run on my computer, and i use a dns address to connect with port 8080. Port 8080 is open in my router's firewall. 
Here is my server code

```
public class Server {

private static int port=8080, maxConnections=0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
int i=0;

try{
  ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port);
  System.out.println("listerner created");
  Socket server;
  System.out.println("socket created");

    while(true){
    doComms connection;
    System.out.println("doCommscreated");
    server = listener.accept();
    System.out.println("accepted");
    doComms conn_c= new doComms(server);
    Thread t = new Thread(conn_c);
    t.start();
  }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
  System.out.println("IOException on socket listen: " + ioe);
  ioe.printStackTrace();
}
}

}
```

When i run the server, I see the msg 'doComms accepted', so i guess its stopping at listener.accept(). (i never see the 'accepted' output.

On the client side, here is the connectoToserver method:

```
private void connectToServer() throws IOException{
    try{
        Log.w("myApp1", "no network");
    connection = new Socket("melucio.no-ip.biz",8080);
    }catch(IOException e){Log.e("myapp", "STACKTRACE");
    Log.e("myapp", Log.getStackTraceString(e));}
}
```

the socket connection is initiated at the beginning of class, before constructor.
The stacktrace is the following:

```
03-11 00:14:57.474: E/myapp(275): STACKTRACE
03-11 00:14:57.474: E/myapp(275): java.net.ConnectException: melucio.no-   ip.biz/24.201.246.8:8080 - Connection refused
03-11 00:14:57.474: E/myapp(275):   at    org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:254)
03-11 00:14:57.474: E/myapp(275):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:219)
03-11 00:14:57.474: E/myapp(275):   at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:781)
03-11 00:14:57.474: E/myapp(275):   at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:194)
03-11 00:14:57.474: E/myapp(275):   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:258)
03-11 00:14:57.474: E/myapp(275):   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:222)
03-11 00:14:57.474: E/myapp(275):   at com.example.client.Sin.connectToServer(Sin.java:109)
03-11 00:14:57.474: E/myapp(275):   at com.example.client.Sin.access$0(Sin.java:106)
03-11 00:14:57.474: E/myapp(275):   at com.example.client.Sin$1.run(Sin.java:38)
03-11 00:14:57.474: E/myapp(275):   at com.example.client.Sin$3.run(Sin.java:157)
03-11 00:14:57.474: W/dalvikvm(275): threadid=8: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-11 00:14:57.474: E/AndroidRuntime(275): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9
03-11 00:14:57.474: E/AndroidRuntime(275): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 00:14:57.474: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.example.client.Sin.sendInfo(Sin.java:118)
03-11 00:14:57.474: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.example.client.Sin.access$1(Sin.java:114)
03-11 00:14:57.474: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.example.client.Sin$1.run(Sin.java:39)
03-11 00:14:57.474: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.example.client.Sin$3.run(Sin.java:157)
```

Thanks a lot to anyone helping me with that, i have no idea what is wrong with it :S

Comment: `everything was working fine until now. I didn't change anything` - oldest developer excuse in the book.

Comment: What errors are there on the server?

Comment: I dont get any error on the server side...the server is just sitting on listener.accept();

Comment: try using telnet melucio.no-ip.biz" 8080

Comment: telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Comment: so not your client code, maybe firewall or dns or server code.

Comment: when the server is running, should i see the port 8080 open in port scan?! Because i dont..The firewall is off on my computer and i opened the 8080 on my router.

Comment: what about the firewall on the server?

Comment: Its the first time i make a client server application and im not use to ports/firewall and all this stuff, but they both run on the same computer, so it should be the same for both i think?! I mean if i opened the port 8080 on my router it should work for both of them?! i think since its local i didn't even have to do it..

Comment: if there are on the same computer then use either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: yes i was going to try that. If it works, it might be something wrong with my dns address?!

Comment: DNS updates sometimes take quite a time.  Plus if they are on the same machine, why bother with the extra hassle of using a public ip address.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure that your server code is the same as what is above and is correct deployed?

Comment: The application is suppose to work ecerywhere, i tried with 10.0.2.2 since im using the emulator and it is working. waybe the dns server si down?! usually i am using melucio.no-ip.biz:3306 for mysql database and its not working either

Comment: what is `10.0.2.2` the address for?

Comment: 10.0.2.2 is localhost when you run on android emulator. yes thats my server file,  its a multithreaded server so when the connection is accepted, it creates a 'doComms' object which to all the job in a thread but it is never created since the server is sitting on accept()

Comment: so what is `24.201.246.8` ?  public ip of `10.0.2.2` ?

Comment: I found it..it is so stupid. my was 192.168.0.100 before, so thats the ip i put in the router configuration to open my ports, but now i have just checked and it has change to 192.168.0.101, I changed it to that and its working. I'm pretty sure it changed when i upgrade to maverick! Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Sorry, not much help this time.

Comment: Dont be sorry, I appreciate the time you took to help me